# ssh command is not working while connecting linux to solaris

Tags: linux, ssh, solaris

I am trying to connect to remote solaris machine from a linux server using ssh but not able to connect to the solaris machine. I am using below ssd command to connect to the solaris machine

```
ssh <host_name>
```

After giving this command, I am not getting any prompt for username and password. Is it the limitation for linux to solaris connection ??

The output is:

```
root@host> ssh -v user@solaris_host
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to solaris_host [solaris_host] port 22.
debug1: connect to address solaris_host port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host solaris_host port 22: Connection timed out
```

Comment: User/Password authentication can be completely disabled. Can you post verbose output as additional information ?

Comment: This may be a case of password-less connection from linux to solaris.

Comment: @fyr my verbose output is                                root@host> ssh -v user@solaris_host
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to solaris_host [solaris_host] port 22.
debug1: connect to address solaris_host port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host solaris_host port 22: Connection timed out

Comment: @erpm31 Connection timed out points usually to a networking problem

Comment: Can other systems connect to the Solaris system using ssh?

Answer (score 1):

Go over following steps

1. Check the network connectivity with your target, e.g. `ping`.
2. Check if the port `22` is open on your remote host e.g. `nmap -A 192.168.0.5/32 -p 22`
3. Check if ssh daemon is running on your target `svcs ssh`

Come back, when the problem still exists.

Comment: ping is working fine, but my machine doesn't support nmap and svcs.

Comment: find an alternative port scanner available in your system, and scan with that. You should run `svcs` on solaris target.